# vb.net - backgroundworker & listview.items.add()

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a vb.net backgroundworker thread for processing and I need to periodically add items to a listview (with multiple columns) during the thread processing.

I can easily use the following code for delegating the task to add an item to a listview, but I can't figure out how to additional info to other columns on the same row.

Anyone help me?

In the thread, I'd execute the following to trigger the invoke to add to listview:

```
AddListItem(ListView1, filepath)
```

Here is the delegate code, if someone can show me how to add the text2 to a 2nd column I'd appreciate it HUGE:

```
Delegate Sub AddListItem_Delegate(ByVal [Label] As ListView, ByVal [text] As String)
Private Sub AddListItem(ByVal [ListView] As ListView, ByVal [text] As String, Optional ByVal [text2] As String = "")
    If [ListView].InvokeRequired Then
        Dim MyDelegate As New AddListItem_Delegate(AddressOf AddListItem)
        Me.Invoke(MyDelegate, New Object() {[ListView], [text]})
    Else
        ListView1.Items.Add([text])
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `ListViewItem`s explicitly as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.aspx) with all necessary subitems and use `ListViewItemCollection.Add` overload that accepts `ListViewItem` as arguments.